# How many Valyrian steel swords are there at the beginning of GoT, and who owns them?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

As of 298 AL, where *A Game of Thrones*  begins, where were the various Valyrian steel weapons that exist?

That is to say, before the 1st chapter starts. The swords are already in someone's hands at the beginning. I just want how many and who owns them. I don't want to know how they pass to new owners as the story progresses.

Comment: You should probably be more specific about what you mean by "beginning". I suppose you mean how many swords have appeared in the books as far as the TV-show has progressed. Which is now up to about half of ASOS.

Comment: @TLP beginning meaning before the 1st chapter starts. The swords are already in someone's hands at the beginning. I just want how many & who owns them. I didn't want how they pass to new owners as the story progresses.

Comment: Aha, I see. And you have not checked [the wikipedia page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyrian_steel) because it contains spoilers? And basically, you just want someone to remove the spoilers and post here? :) You know, the easier way is to read the books and catch up with the rest of the fans, then you can ask any question you want (and there will be many, many questions left to ask).

Comment: @TLP seriously, i didn't think asking who owned the swords would spoil much of the plot. Thanks for warning. I'll refrain from asking further q's till i've read it

Comment: Well, the swords are a focal point of much of the action. You might try checking http://towerofthehand.com/reference/k/01768/index.html -- they have a gadget where you can set your spoiler level so that you do not get spoiled. Though it does not give all that much information.

Comment: Do you count an Arakh as a sword?

Comment: @Marriott81 I assume he means any Valyrian steel weapon.

Comment: @TLP good answer including the axe and the Arakh

Comment: @Marriott81 Thank you, but like I said, its just a copy/paste, so its not really my answer. :)

Comment: @KharoBangdo I've edited your question to better emphasize what you wanted to know. If you do not like the edit, you can use the rollback option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a copy/paste of the relevant parts of the page located at http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyrian_steel **but I have removed all the information that takes place after [298 AL](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Landing#Year_298_after_Aegon.27s_Landing), the beginning of the first book in ASOIAF, *A Game of Thrones*.**

**Blades known to still exist:**

- Ice, the ancestral two handed greatsword of House Stark.
- Heartsbane, the ancestral two handed greatsword of House Tarly, currently in the possession of Lord Randyll Tarly.
- Longclaw, the ancestral Valyrian steel bastard sword of House Mormont. Currently in the possession of Jeor Mormont.
- Lady Forlorn, the ancestral sword of House Corbray, it is currently in the possession of Ser Lyn Corbray.
- Red Rain, the sword of House Drumm stolen in a raid. Given the name and coloring, possibly the ancestral sword of House Reyne
- Nightfall, the ancestral blade of House Harlaw and currently wielded by Ser Harras Harlaw.
- A Valyrian steel axe possessed by House Celtigar.
- Valyrian steel Arakh owned by Caggo (in Essos).

**Blades with unknown fate:**

- Blackfyre, the sword of Aegon I Targaryen. Carried by all Targaryen kings till Aegon IV who gave it to his bastard Daemon Blackfyre who rose in rebellion against the Targaryens, taking the sword's name for his house. Its whereabouts are currently unknown.
- Brightroar, the ancestral sword of House Lannister, lost when King Tommen II Lannister of the Rock sailed to Valyria and never returned.
- Dark Sister, the sword wielded by Visenya Targaryen. The last known owner was Bloodraven.
- Vigilance, ancestral sword of House Hightower.
- Orphan-Maker, ancestral sword of House Roxton.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Caggo was part of the first book?

Comment: Orphan-maker? Jeez... What a happy name.

Comment: @danrhul If you read the comments you will find that the OP does not want to know which weapons were mentioned in the first book, but where all the swords *were* at that point in time.

Comment: @TLP The wording around Caggo's Arakh in no way guarentees that Caggo had it at the time of the first book. You've made an assumption was more my point.

Comment: @danrhul Since many of the weapons are not mentioned until much later in the series (like with Caggo), finding out where they were earlier is not always possible. I don't think the intent of the question is to pinpoint the exact location, but rather to leave out spoilerific information.

Comment: @TLP I know, it's a good answer, I just thought it worth pointing out

Answer (score 15):

At the beginning of the series:

- **Ice**, the ancestral two handed greatsword of House Stark, in possession of Eddard Stark.
- **Heartsbane**, the ancestral two handed greatsword of House Tarly, currently in the possession of Lord Randyll Tarly.
- **Longclaw**, the ancestral Valyrian steel bastard sword of House Mormont, owned by Lord Commander Mormont.
- **Lady Forlorn**, the ancestral sword of House Corbray, it is currently in the possession of Ser Lyn Corbray.
- **Red Rain**, the sword of House Drumm stolen in a raid. Given the name and coloring, possibly the ancestral sword of House Reyne
- **Nightfall**, the ancestral blade of House Harlaw and currently wielded by Ser Harras Harlaw.

[Here is the](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyrian_steel#List_of_known_Valyrian_steel_blades) Wiki article. (Contains **spoilers**, don't read if you haven't read the books)

Comment: I wasn't asking for spoilers. Hence specifically mentioned "beginning". Please edit your answer before i can read it further

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Also, what happened to the Targeryian( spellcheck much??) Swords. Were the above mentioned swords once belonged to targeyrians & then passed to others on their extinction

Comment: You should put the source if it's a direct copy of content on another site.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Are you talking about the family swords of the Targaryens, Blackfyre and Dark Sister? Be careful about what you ask if you don't want to be spoiled, and set a more distinct spoiler depth, in terms of TV-show season or which of the books.

Comment: @KharoBangdo You certainly _were_ asking for spoilers, since there could be a big and surprising revelation in book 4 that someone has had a Valyrian steel sword all along. And that's not just a hypothetical example; there is indeed a Valyrian steel weapon whose existence and location at the beginning of book 1 are a spoiler for what's later revealed.

Comment: I didn't think Valyrian steel swords have magical qualities like they can open parallel universe portals or shoot out green sparks or transform into lightsabers :-p But seriously, i didn't know Valyrian steel swords are extremely significant to the plot. I always considered them as adamantium of the GoT world.

Comment: Besides, i wanted to know how many were there in public knowledge at the beginning & who owned them. Like, every one knows Ned has one. Same as asking where was Ravenclaw's diadem at hp start? It was lost & that was public knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

> The Valyrian steel blades that remain in the world might number in the thousands, but in the Seven Kingdoms there are only 227 such weapons according to Archmaester Thurgood's *Inventories* ...

[The World of Ice and Fire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553805444),
page 15

Answer (score 2):

As a supplementary answer, in [an interview](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/2781), George R. R. Martin has stated that there are many Valyrian Steel swords and that it's not only the Great Houses who own them:

> ...
>   **[Do all the Great Houses own Valyrian steel weapons?]**
>
> Oh, there are more Valyrian swords than we have seen so far. Not all of them belong to the Great Houses. Lesser nobility would oft purchase one as well, for the prestige, and sometimes knights or even lesser swords would acquire one on the battlefield, after the original owner fell. But there have been no more made since the Doom of Valyria.
> <sup>*-So Spake Martin, Entry 2781, [April 16 2008](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/2781).*</sup>