# Why doesn't House Baratheon/House Durrandon have a Valyrian Steel Blade?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The Stormlands and it's inhabitants seem to have a theme of being the most war-like of the Seven Kingdoms, similar to how the Westerlands theme deals with wealth and trickery, the Vale with honour etc, House Durrandon even have "Ours is the Fury" as their house words so why did they in the hundreds of years when they were independent kings acquire a Valyrian Steel blade ?

You would expect as a more martially oriented house to be even more interested in acquiring one than the Lannisters for example.

I included House Baratheon in the title because as they are in spirit and in blood the modern day successor to the Durrandons.

Comment: i think the point is, there are not any left to acquire.

Comment: it also appears the northern houses have them in more abundance, maybe due to the fact they may have been used on the white walkers thousands of years prior.

Comment: I don't know if *every* Westerosi noble house had Valyrian steel swords. They were expensive even before the Doom of Valyria, and after it doubly so.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Why do these five powerful houses not possess Valyrian Steel Swords?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91527/21267)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR We don't know, but probably they never got the chance to acquire one.**

We know next to nothing about how the handful of Valyrian steel blades known to exist came to Westeros in the first place. Their distribution among the noble Westerosi Houses also doesn't tell us much. It doesn't seem to be a matter of wealth (in order to buy one), since the fabulously rich Tyrells (and their predecessors the Gardiners) are not known to have ever possessed one, yet the dirt poor Mormonts have had Longclaw for at least 500 years. It also doesn't seem to be a matter of political power since of the seven Houses that controlled the Seven Kingdoms pre-conquest only the Starks and the Lannisters have had Valyrian swords, yet the majority of the known Valyrian swords are distributed among several lesser vassal Houses.

This leads me to believe that acquiring a Valyrian steel blade is a matter of circumstance. Valyria is the only known source of Valyrian steel (House Targaryen has the distinction of being the only House to have possessed *two* Valyrian steel swords), so we can assume that the Westerosi blades exchanged hands (through war or artifice) until they reached their current owners. House Durrendan (and by extension House Baratheon) may have not had the good fortune of getting a chance of acquiring one.

Comment: Seeing how House Lannister didn't have one for many years, it seems that Valyrian steel would be hard to come by.